# How can set symbol in \itemize

Tags: itemize

How can I set a symbol/icon from [fontawesome](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome?lang=en) package as an itemize `\item` point.

Like, I want to set the `frown-o` or `heart-o` icon as an itemize symbol.

I am on mobile that's why I can not make a figure or code for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See if the following MWE works for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\faFrownO] some text
    \item[\faHeart] some text
    \item[\faHeartO] some text
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]